# CSS table column width uneven

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm new to html and I'm having difficulty creating even column widths within a table, I've tried amending the width several ways including setting the td and th values to 50% but that leaves a large white space to the right. Any pointers on where I've gone wrong would be hugely appreciated! Many thanks!

Snippets below:

```css
/*page content container*/
.content{
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#424242;
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


/*contents tables formating*/
.contenttbl {
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.contenttbl  td,th {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:center; 
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding:5px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:100%;
}

.contenttbl th{
   background-color:#ee3124 ;
   color:white;
}
tr:hover {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
```

```html
<div class="conent">
  <div class="contenttbl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>title1</th>
          <th>title2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>row 1 column 1</td>
          <td>row 1 column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row 2 column 2</td>
          <td>row 2 column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row 3 column 2</td>
          <td>row 3 column 2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `width:100%` for `table` and `width:50%` for `td`, `th`

```css
/*page content container*/
.content{
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#424242;
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


/*contents tables formating*/
.contenttbl {
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:1px solid black;
}

table {
  width:100%;
}

.contenttbl  td,th {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:center; 
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding:5px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:50%;
}

.contenttbl th{
   background-color:#ee3124 ;
   color:white;
}
tr:hover {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="#">
</head>
<body>
    <!--content-->
    <div class="conent">
        <div class="contenttbl">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>title1</th>
                        <th>title2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>row 1 column 1</td>
                        <td>row 1 column 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>row 2 column 2</td>
                        <td>row 2 column 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>row 3 column 2</td>
                        <td>row 3 column 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following to your .css:

```
.contenttbl table {
   width: 100%;
}
```

No need to force td's to a specific width, and this will work for all your .contenttbl tables, regardless of the number of columns you put in them. And it will only affect .contenttbl tables, rather than all tables on your site.

Answer (score 0):

remove the with from td so you're cell's style would be

```css
.contenttbl  td,th {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:center; 
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding:5px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

add the following

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed
}
```